# C++ private char* member allocation failure 'Expression must be a modifiable lvalue'

Tags: c++, arrays, linux, new-operator

I am trying to create a simple exception class but I have encountered this annoying issue and have no idea what's wrong. Please note that I am C++ noob (hence trying to learn how to use new instead of malloc).
Here is the code:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <exception>
#include <string.h>

/**
 * An exception describing a failure in creating a socket.
 */
class SocketCreationException : public std::exception
{
private:
    char *msg;

public:
    ~SocketCreationException()
    {
        delete msg;
    }

    const char *what() const throw()
    {
        const char *str = "Socket creation failure:";
        char *err = strerror(errno);
        msg = new char[strlen(str) + strlen(err) + 1]; // Error here
        return msg;
    }
};
```

EDIT:
A lot of great answers and tips! Thank you all for the help! It's been really useful!

Comment: `what` is `const` qualified. It can't modify member variables. As a possible work-around create the string in the constructor instead. And I really recommend that you pass `errno` as an argument to that constructor. Otherwise, you don't know what might have happened between the error and the calling of the `what` function, the value of `errno` is *indeterminate* unless the previous function failed. Oh, and also use `std::string` instead.

Comment: `what() const` - This affects `msg`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Damn it was that simple. Thanks alot for the quick response.

Comment: @CataCata Don't use `new char[]` here. Use a `std::string` to store the message and let `what()` return `msg.c_str()` instead. You can also use an exception that already has this built-in as a base: [example](https://godbolt.org/z/z63zbT)

Comment: @CataCata You're welcome. It's not for error codes specifically though. [`std::to_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) will convert any of the fundamental arithmetic types to a string.
You may find [`std::error_code`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/error_code) interesting too. You may want to accept that in your constructor instead of an `int`.

Comment: There is also an emerging concern in the code, as `throw()` was deprecated in C++11, and (from memory) is slated for removal in C++20.

Comment: "_I am C++ noob (hence trying to learn how to use new ...)_" That's bad logic! Most users should never need to write `new` or `delete` (nor `malloc` nor `free`) because the standard library provides containers that abstract all that low-level stuff safely behind RAII interfaces. Don't write code to use a feature; use a feature if you need it for a real purpose. And you probably won't need `new`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The member function is const qualified. Therefore it cannot change the values of the members.

In practice, exceptions should initialise their message within their constructor, and only return a pointer to the already constructed message within `what`.

Also, `errno` may have been overwritten by some operation. You should pass the value in the throw expression as an argument to the constructor of your exception.

Also, the class is copyable, but results in undefined behaviour when copied.

Also, if your program compiled, and `what` is called multiple times, then it would leak memory. Also, you never store anything in the allocated memory.

You should probably inherit from `std::runtime_error` which has a constructor accepting the message so that you don't need to implement storing the message yourself, which is actually quite tricky in case of exceptions.

> I am C++ noob (hence trying to learn how to use new

This is not a use case where you should be using `new` (in fact, such use cases are exceedingly rare). If `std::runtime_error` inheritance wasn't a better option, you should be using `std::string` (which you shouldn't use directly with an exception, because copying could potentially throw, but in other cases it is great).

Here is a correct example:

```
class SocketCreationException : public std::runtime_error
{
public:
    SocketCreationException(int number)
        : std::runtime_error(message(number));
    {}

private:
    std::string message(int number)
    {
        return "Socket creation failure: "s
             + std::strerror(number);
    }
};

// usage (immediately after operation that set errno)
int number = errno;
if (number)
    throw SocketCreationException(errno);
```

---

Edit: I forgot bout `std::system_error` which is exactly for this use case, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63688250/2079303) answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
const char *what() const throw()
```

This is a constant class method, that's what the `const` keyword means.

```
msg = new char[strlen(str) + strlen(err) + 1]; // Error here
```

This attempts to modify the `msg` class member. Since this is a constant class method, it cannot do that.

There are three additional fundamental bugs in the shown code:

1. Calling `what()` twice will leak memory.
2. Since the constructor never initializes `msg` to anything, and the destructor `delete`s it, ***not*** calling `what()` will result in memory corruption, and a likely crash. And since there is no copy constructor, copying an object results in a double-`delete` at some point, and another crash.
3. The shown code `new`s the `char` array, for storing the message, but never actually sets it to anything. The returned `what`() string will be complete and total garbage.

You must fix all of these problems, in order for your custom exception object to work correctly.

The simplest fix to all the memory corruption is to simply not do manual memory allocation in the first place.

> Please note that I am C++ noob (hence trying to learn how to use new
> instead of malloc).

Modern C++ code rarely needs to `new` or `delete` anything. Understanding memory allocation is fundamental to C++, of course, but there's rarely a need to actually use it. In this case, a `std::string` does everything that's needed here. So, use `std::string` instead. No need for a destructor. No need to get memory allocation 100% correct, by yourself. Your `std::string` will do it for you.

And to be able to modify the class method in the `const` class method, simply declare it as `mutable`.

```
mutable std::string msg;

// ...

msg="Socket creation failure: ";
msg += strerror(errno);
return msg.c_str();
```

This is much easier that having to calculate and keep track of every individual `char`, and correctly implementing memory allocation logic.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what has been said in the other answers there isn't actually any need to declare a custom exception class here. [`std::system_error`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/system_error/system_error) can already do what you want. For example you can just do:

```
throw std::system_error(errno, std::generic_category(), "Socket creation failure");
```